# ActiveRecord select distinct records having 3 columns in account

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite, activerecord

In the following scenario:

`ClassHour (teacher_id, room_id, hour_id, group_id, subject_id)`

I need to obtain all the class_hours of a given teacher without having the group_id in account.

```
id    teacher_id    room_id    hour_id    group_id    subject_id
1         1            1          1          1            1
2         1            1          1          2            1
3         1            2          2          1            1
4         2            1          3          2            3
```

I need to obtain only `unique records on room_id, hour_id and subject_id` of a given teacher.

This is: `teacher_one.schedule` should return `class_hours with ids [1,3]` because the one with `id == 2` is not unique.

In a nutshell: If my teacher has the id `1`, `teacher.schedule` would need to return:

```
id    teacher_id    room_id    hour_id    group_id    subject_id
1         1            1          1          1            1
3         1            2          2          1            1
```

Comment: Added the desired result, @Strawberry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a HackHands session, we've ended with this, that fully works:

```
class Teacher
  ...
  def schedule
    ids = ClassHour.find_by_sql(['SELECT max(class_hours.id) mid FROM class_hours inner join hours on class_hours.hour_id = hours.id inner join rooms on class_hours.room_id = rooms.id where class_hours.teacher_id = ? group by hours.id, rooms.id', self.id]).map { |x| x['mid'] }
    ClassHour.find ids
  end
end
```

But I don't fully understand why this query works as I want. If someone could explain, it would be great.